# Firebase database get all child

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

I want to get all child from my database. I tried almost similar code like is on YouTube posted by Google Developers, but there were made changes since then. I just want to take all informations that are bellow userdata (there are profiles of users).
My database looks like:
[image: tree representation of data]

and I want to get all informations that are under **`userdata`**
Here is my code.

```
FirebaseDatabase database5 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef5 = database5.getReference("userdata");

    myRef5.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
            map.getClass();
            Log.i("Mufz", "Value is: " + map.getClass());


 //                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), `value3.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

after running this there nothing happens and it runs prevoroius activity or there come error

```
08-16 19:29:47.225 32507-32507/com.samo.facedatefb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.samo.facedatefb, PID: 32507
                                                                 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.samo.facedatefb.MapsActivity$3.onDataChange(MapsActivity.java:306)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaie.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaje.zzcta(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajh$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5549)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

Where could be a problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
```

To

```
Map<String, Object> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GenericTypeIndicator` class to marshal the data.
As per the documentation:

> Due to the way that Java implements generics (type-erasure), it is
>   necessary to use a slightly more complicated method to properly
>   resolve types for generic collections at runtime.

Instead of this:

```
Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
```

Use a GenericTypeIndicator:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
    // whenever data at this location is updated.
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>> m = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>>(){};
        Map<String, Object> map = snapshot.getValue(m);
        long age = (long)map.getValue("age");

        Log.i("Mufz", "User Data Value is: " + snapshot.getKey());
        Log.i("Mufz", "User Name Value is: " + map.getValue("username"));
        Log.i("Mufz", "User Age Value is: " + age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and same like before. After a while it started MainActivity, like restarted app. Or when i debugged the app there came simillar error that I posted :/

Comment: My fault, I overlooked reference you were using. If you want to add a listener to your "userdata" node then you will need to iterate through the each child node. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Big thanks to you man for being so helpful, It worked :)
And if you could just one more thing. As you can see I have under all "userprofile" age too. So it threw error to me that Long couldn't be converted to String so I had to delete this field and everything worked perfectly. But is tehre way to get all field included age? Thanks

Comment: No problem.  If you want to mix data types and store them in the same Map object one way you can do this is to use a Map of this type: Map<String, Object>. Then when you get each map entry you cast it to the appropriate type. I'll edit my answer again to show so you can keep the age value.

Comment: Yes man, sorry that I didn't reply, big thanks to you, It really helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `DataSnapshot` will give you an `array` not an `object`. Then maybe you can try something like this:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        YourObject obj = snapshot.getValue(YourObject.class);
    }
}
```